# About $f(x)$ satisfying $f(0) = 0, f(1) =1, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 4$, and $f'(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus

let $f(x)$ be a function such that

$$f(0) = 0$$

$$f(1) =1$$ $$f(2) = 2$$ $$f(3) = 4$$ $$f'(x) \text{is differentiable on } \mathbb{R}$$ Prove that there is a number in the interval $(0,3)$ such
that $0 < f''(x)<1$

I'm really stuck.
thanks

Comment: Everything! Like MVT

Comment: Use the Mean Value Theorem, several times.

Comment: Can you please show me

Comment: @SimonS I need a hint

Comment: Ok, it's the second derivative. Did I read incorrectly first time?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Show that a some point $x \in (0,1)$, $f'(x) = 1$. Then for some $y \in (2,3)$, $f'(y) = 2$. Now use that to deduce the result by applying the MVT again.

*Added:*

Having found such $x$ and $y$, there must be a $z \in (x,y)$ such that

$$f''(z) = \frac{f'(y) - f'(x)}{y - x}$$

Now think about how you can bound that expression above and below.

Comment: i still dont get it. can you further explain the last part. how do i deduce the result

Comment: Added detail above.

Answer (score 0):

In the interval $(2,3)$ we can get $f'(\xi)=2$, and in $(0,1)$ we can get $f'(\delta)=1$, so in $[\delta,\xi]$ we can get $0<f"(\theta)<1$, considering $\xi-\delta>1$.

Answer (score 0):

$1=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=f'(\xi_1),\xi_1\in(0,1)$

$2=\frac{f(3)-f(2)}{3-2}=f'(\xi_2),\xi_2\in(2,3)$

then $\xi_2-\xi_1\in(1,3)$

$f''(\eta)=\frac{f'(\xi_2)-f'(\xi_1)}{\xi_2-\xi_1}=\frac{1}{\xi_2-\xi_1}\in(\frac{1}{3},1),\eta\in(\xi_1,\xi_2)\subset(0,3)$

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest as a first attempt, curve fitting a polynomial. Let's fit to a cubic, since the general cubic equation has four parameters (and you have four known points).
$$f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$
$$f(0) = a*0^3+b*0^2+c*0+d = 0 \rightarrow d = 0$$
$$f(1) = a*1^3+b*1^2+c*1+d = 1 \rightarrow a+b+c=1$$
$$f(2) = a*2^3+b*2^2+c*2+d = 2 \rightarrow 8a+4b+2c = 2$$
$$f(3) = a*3^3+b*3^2+c*3+d = 4 \rightarrow 27a+9b+3c = 4$$
Solving the last three equations simultaneously gives us:
$$a=-\frac{1}{2}, b=\frac{3}{2}, c = 0$$
Therefore, the actual cubic equation that will pass through all these points is:
$$f(x)=\frac{-x^3}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{2}$$
Since we have the actual function, let's take the derivative:
$$f'(x)=\frac{-3x^2}{2}+3x$$
$$f''(x)=-3x+3$$
Since we have the second derivative being linear, we can figure out where the point $f(x)=0.5$ is. If that point lies inside $(0,3)$, then we have proven the function.
$$f''(x)=3-3x=0.5 \rightarrow x=\frac{-2.5}{-3}=\frac{5}{6}$$
This is inside the domain of the function, so we are good.

Alternatively, we could use the MVT like others have done and say:
$$f''(0)=3$$
$$f''(3)=-6$$
Since the second derivative is continuous (a straight line), by the MVT there exists a value in $(0,3)$ such that $0<f''(x)<1$.

Comment: The question is not about finding _some_ $f$ for which the desired property is true, but about showing that it must be true for _every_ $\mathcal C^2$ function that passes through the given points.